# onClick loses focus

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

i have this search bar component. it has a drop down div when you search something on it. The problem is that i dont want the drop down menu to show if the component is not in focus. I have this code:

```
type Props = {
    onClickResult: (result: string, key: number) => void
    placeHolder: string
    results: string[]
    holdValue: boolean
}

const SearchBar = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('')
    const [results, setResults] = useState<string[]>(props.results)
    const [searchFocus, setSearchFocus] = useState<boolean>(false)

    function handleChooseResult(result: string, key: number) {
        // props.onClickResult(result, key)
        console.log(result);
        
        props.holdValue ? setSearch(result) : setSearch('')
    }

    return (
        <div id="search-component">
            <div className="search-bar">
                <FaSearch id="search-icon"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder={props.placeHolder} value={search} onChange={
                    (e) => setSearch(e.target.value)
                }
                onFocus={() => setSearchFocus(true)} onBlur={() => setSearchFocus(false)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="search-results">
                { searchFocus &&
                    <ul>
                        {results.filter((result) =>
                            result.substring(0, search.length).toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()        
                        ).map((result, key) => 
                            <li key={key} onClick={() => handleChooseResult(result, key)}>{result}</li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the problem is that if im checking for searchFocus to render the drop down, the onClick function doesnt work

Comment: <div className="search-bar"> change to <form className="search-bar" />, and then  bring the seearch result component inside <form /> tag, use onBlur on on form tag, this use can prevent unnecessary onBlur, If you want a code sample. you can upvote this comment

Comment: How results array look like? some samples